# C++: Using templated typedef in two classes

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

Hi I have the following classes:

```
template<class T>
class RandomTree<T> {
private:
    RandomTreeNode root;
    typedef double (*funcion_ptr) (T, T);

public:
    RandomTree(std::vector<function_ptr> functions){...}
};

template<class T>
class RandomTreeNode<T> {
private:
    typedef double (*funcion_ptr) (T, T);
    function_ptr function;
public:
    RandomTreeNode(function_ptr function){...}
};
```

The tree is given a vector of function pointers and each node is created and has one particular function. Is there a way for me to not have to define the `typedef double (*function_ptr) (T,T)` in both classes?

Comment: Note that your class definitions have an extra `<T>` behind their names that should not be there. See my answer for the corrected syntax of declaring  class templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are declaring a free-standing function pointer type, as opposed to a member-function pointer, you could of course put the typedef in a separate templated class in global scope or in a namespace, so it can be accessed by both classes.

Like this:

```
template<class T>
struct RandomTreeFunction
{
    typedef double (*function_ptr)(T, T);
};

template<class T>
class RandomTree<T> {
private:
    typedef typename RandomTreeFunction<T>::function_ptr function_ptr;
    ...
};
```

I also recommend you to look into using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead.

Comment: is std::function implemented in the MinGW g++ compiler? It doesn't seem to be compiling for me

Comment: Aso we need to type typedef **typename** RandomTreeFunction<T>::function_ptr function_ptr as the compiler needs to know its a nested type and not a member variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you make it public in `RandomTreeNode<T>` you can say then:

```
template<class T>
class RandomTree<T> {
    typedef RandomTreeNode<T>::funcion_ptr function_ptr;
};
```

or use `RandomTreeNode<T>::funcion_ptr` directly, which would be quite tedious.

Answer (score 0):

If you have acccess to a compiler (e.g. gcc >= 4.7, clang >= 3.0) that supports **template aliases**, you can do something like

```
#include <vector>

template<class T>
using function_ptr = double (*)(T,T);  

template<class T>
class RandomTreeNode {
private:
    function_ptr<T> function;
public:
    RandomTreeNode(function_ptr<T> function){/*...*/}
};

template<class T>
class RandomTree {
private:
    RandomTreeNode<T> root;

public:
    RandomTree(std::vector<function_ptr<T>> functions){/*...*/}
};
```

Otherwise, the solution by Joachim Pileborg is adequate.